# Uncaught Error: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR при создании элемента с помощью createElement

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function mar(direct) {
   var marq =  document.createElement('<marquee direction="' + direct + '" loop="1" scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="30"'); //Uncaught Error: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5 
   marq.appendChild(document.body);
}
</script>
<body style="margin:0">
<img onclick="mar('down');" src="1.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;>
<img onckic="mar('up');" src="2.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;>
</body>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement  
Да и вообще прочитайте сперва про DOM, а потом применяйте.  
Так с DOM не работают. Должно быть нечто вроде:  

    marq=document.createElement("marquee");
    marq.direction=direct;
    ...
    document.body.appendChild(marq);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указывать можно только тэг.

[Читать](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement)